# How to get image from the database in lumen api?

Tags: lumen

I have tried as a get data normally but in json response show error in image field. Below code is right ??

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admin', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('profile_pic');  
});
```

and for get data below code

```
public function log() {

        $users = AdminLogin::all();

        return response()->json($users);
    }
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$photo = $this->uploadFile->get_by_photo($photo, ['filename']); 
$path = storage_path('app') . '/' . $photo[0]['filename']; 
$type = File::mimeType($path); 
$headers = array('Content-Type' => $type); 
$response = response()->download($path, $photo, $headers); ob_end_clean(); 
return $response;
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged, consider adding a bit of explanation. And please: learn how to properly format your content.

Comment: but I am a new in stack and my account is banned for ask question so I write an answer @ GhostCat

Comment: Then why not put in the small effort to write a *decent* answer, one that *explains* your posted code and your solution?

Comment: When your account got **banned** from asking questions - then because of **you** violating the policies of this site. And your reaction to that: **another** violation of our rules. So please: **read** about the rules of this community, and learn to behave. Instead of **again** doing something that will only create negative feedback. And when you do knot know what you are doing ... then consider deleting your question. It doesn't help this site when you put up content that nobody understands.